# On Javascript or JQuery, while running add/remove mousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the location when I first click on the screen.I did this. But i need more.
The mousemove event will also run when the mousedown event runs. mousemove event will not work when mouseup event runs

```
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
        console.log("First: down position: " + e.pageX + "---" + e.pageY);
        canvasMove("canvas");
    });

    $("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
        console.log("Last: up position: " + e.pageX + "---" + e.pageY);
    });
    function canvasMove(id) {
        $(id).mousemove(function (e) {
            console.log("move position: " + e.pageX + "---" + e.pageY);
        });
    }
```

So how do I remove the mousemove event in the mouseup event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#canvas").off('mousemove')
```

If you have something else listening to the mouse you can attach your handler with a namespaced event like

```
$("#canvas").on('mousemove.loggingPosition')
```

and then remove it

```
$("#canvas").off('mousemove.loggingPosition')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `on` and `off` methods:

```
function canvasMove(id) {
    $(id).on("mouseup",function (e) {
        $( this ).off("mousemove");
        console.log("move position: " + e.pageX + "---" + e.pageY);
    });
}
```

For more info visit [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: bind and unbind have been deprecated - use on and off instead